# Why "models aren't loaded yet" error shows when using embedded models?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, django-admin, djongo

I'm trying to connect my django app with mongoDB, I have been using [djongo](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo) for that. When I create a simple model with no embedded documents the migrations runs perfect but when I try to create a embedded model document in my model the "models aren't loaded yet" error show when running `python manage.py makemigrations`.

I would like to know first why this error appears and why it happens when I use embedded models.

Python Code:

- Project Tree

```sh
➜  reports tree
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── rep
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── models.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── reports
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py

5 directories, 19 files
```

- rep/models.py

```py
from djongo import models
from django import forms



class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('name', 'tagline')

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author 
        fields = ('name', 'email')


class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.EmbeddedField(
        model_container=Blog,
        model_form_class=BlogForm
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 225)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    authors = models.ArrayField(
        model_container=Author,
        model_form_class=AuthorForm
   )
```

- Traceback

```sh
(django-djongo) ➜  reports python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jagl/Documents/Learning/Programming/Django/reports/rep/models.py", line 31, in <module>
    class Entry(models.Model):
  File "/home/jagl/Documents/Learning/Programming/Django/reports/rep/models.py", line 34, in Entry
    model_form_class=BlogForm
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 225, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_container, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 87, in __init__
    self._validate_container()
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/djongo/models/fields.py", line 91, in _validate_container
    for field in self.model_container._meta.get_fields():
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 734, in get_fields
    return self._get_fields(include_parents=include_parents, include_hidden=include_hidden)
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 794, in _get_fields
    all_fields = self._relation_tree
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 707, in _relation_tree
    return self._populate_directed_relation_graph()
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 678, in _populate_directed_relation_graph
    all_models = self.apps.get_models(include_auto_created=True)
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 178, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/home/jagl/.virtualenvs/django-djongo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 140, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

I am using:

```
son==0.5.8
dataclasses==0.7
Django==2.2.12
djongo==1.3.2
pymongo==3.10.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
```

The only answers I have find are those that explains how to use models when using a script but that is not my case. Thanks for the help

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem